# MySQL Selecting From a Table name matching string

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to SQL and I've been having trouble trying to figure out how to select rows from a table that matches a string.
The name of the table uses the current month and year. 
It looks like this:

```
XXXX.xxx_YY_MM
```

where XXXX is the database, YY is year, and MM is month. 
So normally the query would just look like this:

```
select * from XXXX.xxx_16_05;
```

However, I want it to be able to change depending on the date.
So I thought this would work:

```
select * from (select concat('XXXX.xxx_',date_format(now(), '%y_%m'))));
```

The concat bit gives me something that looks exactly like the name of the table. But it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. It says every table must have it's own alias. I'm not sure what to do about it.

Alternatively, I was thinking maybe something like this would be ok

```
 select * from  (select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like concat('%logsms_',date_format(now(), '%y_%m'),'%'));
```

But it doesn't work either. What should I do? There is only one table with a name that matches the string.

Comment: What are you using to manipulate the DB? 
In php, I would take the current date with a function of php then trim it down to what you desire, and just use the variable in the query. This, however does not work if the month changes, and you want to access the table for the previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an expression for the table name in SQL. You need to use a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL and executes it using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM XXXX.xxx_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y_%m'));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

A database design that requires this seems like a poor decision. You should have a single table where the date is in a column, not separate tables for each month.

If you're running the query from a programming language, you can use its own date functions to constructure SQL.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm (after I took out the '@' in '@stmt'). I wasn't  familiar with the whole PREPARE and EXECUTE statements yet but I guess now I'll have to look into them because the seem very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following query to retrieve all table by matching string.

```
select table_schema as database_name,table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_name like '%your_table_name%' order by table_schema, table_name;
```